# Как расположить микросервисы в репозитории?

Tags: docker, архитектура, jenkins, микросервисы, kubernetes

Вопрос в следующем: будет N количество микросервисов, как их положить в ГИТ лучше всего?

Каждый микросервис в отдельный репозиторий или можно описывать все в одном репозитории?

В дальнейшем планируем подключать k8s, чтобы поднимать копии сервисов автоматом.

Правильно понимаю, что в Jenkins'e будут собираться образы для docker'a, а потом уже эти образы будут использоваться в k8s?

Если так, то как в Jenkins'e быть с тем, что я поменял только, например, 3-ий из 10 микросервисов и надо пересобирать только его, а остальные не трогать, а докер образ сделать только для 3-го микросервиса (в случае, если все микросервисы будут в одном репозитории).

Comment: Я бы хранил отдельный микросервис в своем репозитории.

Comment: Обычно у каждого микросервиса свой репозиторий, свой пайплайн, свои настройки для билда/теста/деплоймента. Всё своё короче.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Каждый микросервис в отдельный репозиторий или можно описывать все в
> одном репозитории?

Существует концепция Twelve-Factor App, в рамках которой оптимальным считается "Одно приложение — один репозиторий".

> Правильно понимаю, что в Jenkins'e будут собираться образы для
> docker'a, а потом уже эти образы будут использоваться в k8s?

Вариантов можно придумать много, но именно такой подход верный

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, возьмем на заметку.

Answer (score 2):

> Вопрос в следующем: будет N количество микросервисов, как их положить
> в ГИТ лучше всего?

Лучше или хуже? Вы собираетесь готовить или будите спрашивать только рецепты?

> Каждый микросервис в отдельный репозиторий или можно описывать все в
> одном репозитории?

Этот вопрос скорее к Вам. Как Вам удобно. Можно и так и так. Блюд много вкусы разные. Я уверен что найдётся сторонники любой концепции.

> В дальнейшем планируем подключать k8s, чтобы поднимать копии сервисов
> автоматом.
>
> Правильно понимаю, что в Jenkins'e будут собираться образы для
> docker'a, а потом уже эти образы будут использоваться в k8s?

Это как вы настроите. Но идея любого CI-CD автоматизировать все повторяющиеся процессы и сконцентрироваться на основном.

> Если так, то как в Jenkins'e быть с тем, что я поменял только,
> например, 3-ий из 10 микросервисов и надо пересобирать только его, а
> остальные не трогать, а докер образ сделать только для 3-го
> микросервиса (в случае, если все микросервисы будут в одном
> репозитории).

Ну смотрите, если вы решили приготовить кашу у вас соответственно не должна возникать задача после выделить гречку и блюда. Если вы решили готовить всё вместе то и употреблять будите также.
Есть плюсы минусы у всего. Держать всё вместе легко готовить, накидал и вот тебе каша. Задействовано минимально инструментов. Готовить раздельно - это отдельные не большие блюда в отдельной посуде, готовить следить накладно но в результате вариаций на много больше. Обмануть не получится.

На сегодняшний день я б пошел другим путем.

1. Сделал бы один репозиторий.
2. Начал с монолита который очень хорошо разделён на слои и модули
3. Довел бы его очень быстро до MVP с хорошим CI-CD
4. Начал распиливать на микросервисы если возникает в этом необходимость (она может никогда не возникнуть между прочим), раскладывая каждый новый сервис в свою репу
5. И каждый интегрировал отдельно к монолиту.

Ваше приложение будет неизбежно дописываться и переписываться частично или полностью на протяжении всей разработки. Не нужно этого боятся это часть жизни. Повар который боиться испортить блюдо не повар.

Comment: Нет, монолит делать смысла нет, т.к. он сейчас и есть монолитный, уже есть трудности с определенными вещами в монолите. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @OwDafuq, если монолит есть то пункты 4 и 5. Распиливайте потихоньку критические места, пилить всё также нет необходимости сразу. Я сторонник эволюционной теории - когда вы шаг за шагом выпиливаете куски из монолита. Но в любом случае хороших блюд на вашей кухне

Comment: Да изначально проект должен был быть в виде микросервисов, т.к. по ТЗ явно это требовалось, но из-за сжатых сроков был сделан как монолит. Начинаем пилить с критических моментов как раз) Спасибо!

Comment: Эт нормально. Удачи